# How to fix "Ambiguous column name" in a h2 db

Tags: sql, h2

I have a h2 database setup. In my tables, that are being used by the sql query, there are no ambiguous column names, but the query always fails due to that.

[db setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlqH5.png)

I've tried to minimise the sql statement and removing the inner joins seem to remove the problem, though it also removed the functionality.

I've also tried to specify a table name for every column in the query, with no luck.

```
Select user.username, roles.role
from User
inner join user-roles on(user.id=user-roles.user_id)
inner join roles on(user-roles.roles_id=roles.id)
where user.username='root';
```

Comment: Could there be a problem with the table name `user-roles`?  That would normally not be allowed in SQL, unless it were escaped.

Comment: I indeed had to put it in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this...

```
SELECT 
U.username, 
R.role
FROM [User] U
INNER JOIN [user-roles] UR ON U.id = UR.[user_id]
INNER JOIN [roles] R ON UR.role_id=R.id
WHERE U.username='root';
```

Comment: I ended up replacing the [] brackets with double quotes " , removing the brackets on user_id and fixed Capitalisation on the Table names.
I guess it was just little differences in sql. Thanks.

Comment: Thats my pleasure :)